# Input Match in CLIPS, Syntax error

Tags: clips

I have to enter a symptom and want to get name of problems but when I wrote defrule checking-input, i got an error. code is following , please help
I think , problem is in defrule checking-input

```
    (deftemplate probelm
    (multislot name)
    (slot symptom))

    (deffacts probelms
(probelm (name Faulty-Spark-Plug,Low-air-pressure-in-Tyres,Fuel-Injector-Leakage,Bad-Engine-Oil) 
        (symptom High-fuel-consumption))
(probelm (name Faulty-Spark-Plug , Fuel-injector-Problem) 
        (symptom Lack-of-acceleration))
(probelm (name Loose-or-Dry-belt,misalignment-belt,bearing-of-motor) 
        (symptom Squeaky-belt-noise))
(probelm (name Low engine Oil) 
        (symptom Blue-Smoke))
(probelm (name Coolant level,transmission fluid level low) 
        (symptom White-Smoke))
(probelm (name Air filter Or fuel injector problem,fuel pressure regualtor) 
        (symptom Black-Smoke))
        )


  (defrule reading-input
   =>
  (printout t "Enter the symptom your car Shows: " )
  (assert (var (read))))



 (defrule checking-input
 (var ?symptom)
 (probelm  (symptom ?symptom1)(name $?name1))
 (test (member$ ?name ?name1)) 
   =>
  (printout t "Problems can be " ?name1 crlf))
```

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

1. you need to use (create$ element1 element2 ...)  to create your
   multislot, you cannot separate elements with a comma (,) as you did
2. you need to call (reset) to load deffacts
3. your checking-input
   rule use a handler without defining it first (?name)

Here your working script:

```
(deftemplate probelm
    (multislot name)
    (slot symptom))

    (deffacts probelms
(probelm (name (create$ "Air filter"  "fuel injector problem" "fuel pressure regualtor")) 
        (symptom Black-Smoke))
        )
;; add others problems
        (reset)

  (defrule reading-input
   =>
  (printout t "Enter the symptom your car Shows: " )
  (assert (var (read))))



 (defrule checking-input
 (var ?symptom)
 (probelm  (symptom ?symptom1)(name $?name1))
 (test (eq ?symptom ?symptom1)) 
   =>
  (printout t "Problems can be " $?name1 crlf))

 (run)

 (exit)
```

Bye
Nicola

PS: remember to vote the answer if useful;)

Comment: thanks dear. i came up with true solution.. thanks alot :)